# Roulette, selecting image

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a "roulette" script, but I have some problems. I'm trying to make it this way:

- If I click start, I want to highlight one by one from the beginning to the end.
- After a random amount of loops(from the beginning to the end), stop it also on the random image and highlight it with a green border (winner) and alert `data-id`.

At the moment, whenever I click start, it starts to highlight every image, but the border is not removed on previous ones. I don't really know how to achieve that.

My code:

```js
function start() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll(".roulette-item");
  play(el, el.length);
};

function play(el, length) {
  var item = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    el[item].style.border = "3px solid yellow";
    if (item == length) {
      item = 0;
  } else {
      item++;
    }
  }, 200);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <img data-id="0" class="grid-cell roulette-item" src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
  <img data-id="1" class="grid-cell roulette-item" src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
  <img data-id="2" class="grid-cell roulette-item" src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
  <img data-id="3" class="grid-cell roulette-item" src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
  <img data-id="4" class="grid-cell roulette-item" src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
  <img data-id="5" class="grid-cell roulette-item" src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
  <img data-id="6" class="grid-cell roulette-item" src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
  <img data-id="7" class="grid-cell roulette-item" src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
  <img data-id="8" class="grid-cell roulette-item" src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
</div>

<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
```

Generally, I am new to this, so sorry that my code looks ugly.

---

Additional Question:

- Is it safe to use that kind on "roulette" together with PHP? I mean, could it easily be manipulated?

Comment: Any client-side code (i.e., JavaScript running on the browser) can easily be manipulated.

Comment: For example, if you're going to send a request to a PHP endpoint after picking the random image, someone could just manually send the request and circumvent the randomness. I would pick the random item on the server with PHP, and then have the JavaScript cycle through highlighting the images one-by-one and stop on the image that the server side code picked.

Comment: Alright! I'll try :)

Comment: To bounce off what Nathan said; NEVER trust anything that is displayed server side. EVER. PERIOD. Generate a hash SERVERSIDE, display the "roulette" based off of the HASH and then compare the HASH. Anything client-side can be manipulated with a simple "Right Click + Inspect Element" then overwrite the desired element. Eg "lose -> win". Additionally, don't put how to make the hash in the JS because they can be interrogated with the same principle and then used to brute force create hashes until one wins.

Comment: I thought about something less complicated.
Such as, whenever i hit "Roll" i call a function on server which return random number within 1 and 10, and it will be the number of how many times it gonna loop throught images, and id of element it should stop at. And then, echo it as a function parameter on client-side. Is it enough? :P

Comment: @Suttero That's essentially what I had in mind. As long as the pick is generated and saved (if you're saving it to DB/session/etc) on the server side, you should be good. The key is to put any decision logic that could affect the status of a user or other users on the server side.

Comment: Okey, managed to make it work. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are adding a style to the element, but are not removing it from the previous element. Using your code, you can make this adjustment:

```
function play(el, length) {
    var item = length - 1;
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        el[item].style.border = "";
        item = (item + 1) % length;
        el[item].style.border = "3px solid yellow";
    }, 200);
}
```

---

If you are new to Web Development, you could consider using CSS to describe your border like so:

```
.highlighted {
    border: 3px solid yellow;
}
```

and when you run your roulette, you should append and remove the class as appropriate

```
function play(el, length) {
    var item = length - 1;
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        el[item].classList.add("border");
        item = (item + 1) % length;
        el[item].classList.remove("border");
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: im getting: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined with first example. Hm

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I went out of bounds with my indexing. This should be correct.